# Bootstrap changing background-color

Tags: html, css, background-color

Working on a quote generator website. I added bootstrap, and in the css code, I have a part where I set the HTML element's background-color to a blue-green mix shade. bootstrap just decides to override the CSS code and sets the part of the page that has content's background color to white. Why and how can I keep my background-color to what I want it to be

```js
var quotes = [
    [
        "To be prepared for war is one of the most effectual means of preserving peace.",
        "George Washington"
    ],
    [
        "One man with courage is a majority.",
        "Thomas Jefferson"
    ],
    [
        "National honor is a national property of the highest value.",
        "James Monroe"
    ],
    [
        "The only thing we have to fear is fear itself.",
        "Theodore D. Roosevelt"
    ],
    [
        "Ask not what your country can do for you, but what you can do for your country.",
        "John F. Kennedy"
    ]
    
];
var currentQuote = 0;
function showNewQuote() {
 if (currentQuote >= 5) {
  currentQuote = 0; 
 }
 var Quote = [quotes[currentQuote][0], quotes[currentQuote][1]];
 document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "\"" + Quote[0] + "\"";
 document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = Quote[1];
 currentQuote++;
}
```

```css
html {
 background-color: #33cccc;
}

#header, #paragraph {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 
}

#header {
 padding-top: 10%;
 font-size: 60px;
}

#paragraph {
 padding-left: 80%;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class = "container">
    <h1 id="header">Click the button to generate a quote!</h1>
 <p id="paragraph"></p>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="showNewQuote()">Generate New Quote</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:
Make sure your css is loaded **after** the `bootstrap.css` file.

```js
var quotes = [
    [
        "To be prepared for war is one of the most effectual means of preserving peace.",
        "George Washington"
    ],
    [
        "One man with courage is a majority.",
        "Thomas Jefferson"
    ],
    [
        "National honor is a national property of the highest value.",
        "James Monroe"
    ],
    [
        "The only thing we have to fear is fear itself.",
        "Theodore D. Roosevelt"
    ],
    [
        "Ask not what your country can do for you, but what you can do for your country.",
        "John F. Kennedy"
    ]
    
];
var currentQuote = 0;
function showNewQuote() {
 if (currentQuote >= 5) {
  currentQuote = 0; 
 }
 var Quote = [quotes[currentQuote][0], quotes[currentQuote][1]];
 document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "\"" + Quote[0] + "\"";
 document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = Quote[1];
 currentQuote++;
}
```

```html
<script src = "script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style>
body {
 background-color: #33cccc;
}

#header, #paragraph {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 
}

#header {
 padding-top: 10%;
 font-size: 60px;
}

#paragraph {
 padding-left: 80%;
 font-size: 20px;
}
  </style>
<body>
 <div class = "container">
    <h1 id="header">Click the button to generate a quote!</h1>
 <p id="paragraph"></p>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="showNewQuote()">Generate New Quote</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Option 2:
Use the `!important` keyword:

```js
var quotes = [
    [
        "To be prepared for war is one of the most effectual means of preserving peace.",
        "George Washington"
    ],
    [
        "One man with courage is a majority.",
        "Thomas Jefferson"
    ],
    [
        "National honor is a national property of the highest value.",
        "James Monroe"
    ],
    [
        "The only thing we have to fear is fear itself.",
        "Theodore D. Roosevelt"
    ],
    [
        "Ask not what your country can do for you, but what you can do for your country.",
        "John F. Kennedy"
    ]
    
];
var currentQuote = 0;
function showNewQuote() {
 if (currentQuote >= 5) {
  currentQuote = 0; 
 }
 var Quote = [quotes[currentQuote][0], quotes[currentQuote][1]];
 document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = "\"" + Quote[0] + "\"";
 document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = Quote[1];
 currentQuote++;
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #33cccc !important;
}

#header, #paragraph {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 
}

#header {
 padding-top: 10%;
 font-size: 60px;
}

#paragraph {
 padding-left: 80%;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class = "container">
    <h1 id="header">Click the button to generate a quote!</h1>
 <p id="paragraph"></p>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="showNewQuote()">Generate New Quote</button>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Note that I also made a change from `html` to `body` in your css)

Comment: Thanks it worked. It won't let me mark this as the answer until 5 minutes passes, but I'll mark it when the cooldown finishes. It works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above first load bootstrap and then your css.
Instead of using !important you could use your browsers dev-tools (I recommend Chromes) and look for the selector of the bootstraps background color.
Its specificity is in most times pretty hide and you have to add a higher specificity for your style.

Read this article on MDN for more information:
[MDN CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)